# How to update nested objects after strong_parameters update on rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I've been using strong_parameters gem with Rails 3.2 for quite a while now. And up to now everything was ok.

After recent update of strong_parameters to v0.2.0 I no longer can update nested objects.

Here are request params

```
{
  "resource"=>{
    "name"=>"1362483207-11-offer",
    "slug"=>"1362483207-11-offer",
    "code"=>"136248320711",
    "category_id"=>"4",
    "price"=>"100",
    "short_description"=>"",
    "description"=>"",
    "offer_card_types_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"id"=>"11", "card_type_id"=>"1"},
      "1"=>{"card_type_id"=>"0"},
      "2"=>{"card_type_id"=>"0"},
      "3"=>{"card_type_id"=>"0"}
    },
    "show_banner"=>"1",
    "autoclaim"=>"1",
    "published"=>"0",
    "number_of_codes_to_generate"=>"",
    "images_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"retained_image"=>"", "_destroy"=>"true", "id"=>"1"},
      "on-1362560061857"=>{
        "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000080ef654f8 ... >
      }
    },

    "partner_id"=>"2",
    "all_checkout_places"=>"0",
    "offer_checkout_places_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"checkout_place_id"=>"0"},
      "1"=>{"id"=>"11", "checkout_place_id"=>"7"},
      "2"=>{"checkout_place_id"=>"0"},
      "3"=>{"checkout_place_id"=>"0"},
      "4"=>{"checkout_place_id"=>"0"}
    }
  },
  "id"=>"11"
}
```

I've tried params this and params that. I simply doesn't update nested objects.
Please help

At first I thought that `params.require(:resource).permti(..., :images => [])` should do the trick, however it failed, then I tried various other options. They all failed.

How can I permit all these nested object.

Comment: can you put your model code? Its probably an issue with mass assignment (attr_accessible)

Comment: attr_accessible is not an issue. In fact I don't use it

```config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs? The key for the nested attributes will be `images_attributes`, not `images`. That's what you need to pass in the `permit()` method to make it work.

Comment: I tried that either. It doesn't work. Apparently this issue is not resolved:
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/pull/121#issuecomment-15469655
and other issues